# php artisan command isn't working.

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

After installing composer and installing laravel using laravel installer,
I can create project, but not being able to run php artisan command. 
it is giving following error

> kickass@kickass-UX303LB:~/a$ php artisan
>   PHP Warning:  require(/home/kickass/a/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kickass/a/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/kickass/a/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/kickass/a/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

what is wrong? 
I tried running composer install and composer update, didn't help.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the autoloader files, since the `vendor/autoload.php` file seems to be missing.

Comment: did that,
this time, PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory' not found in /home/kickass/a/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 356

Comment: Try deleting the `vendor` directory and running `composer install` after that. Also please be mindful of the output of the installation command and make sure no errors are thrown.

Comment: autoload.php, composer

Comment: removed the vendor directory and ran composer install, same error

Comment: I'm assuming the install process when on without any errors. If that's the case, a second question: who is the owner and what are the permissions of the `vendor` directory?

Comment: Looks like a permission issue to me.

Comment: Can I ask are you running on your local machine or a VM  (such as a Laravel-Homestead vagrant setup?)

Comment: give permission to your storage folder.
chmod -R 777 storage